# Django signals / notification system

Tags: django, signals

Is it a good aproach to use Django signals to implement email notification system? I have `CustomUser` model related with `CustomUserPreferences` planned as follows:

```
class CustomUserPreferences(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=None, on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)
    lesson_notification = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    journal_notification = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    login_notification = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    excercise_notification = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    homework_notification = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ...
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    preferences = models.OneToOneField(CustomUserPreferences, null = True ,default=None, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(to = 'self', related_name = 'teachers', symmetrical = False, blank = True)
```

Whenever a new object of lets say `Lesson` is created I want to send an email to the user and that's fine - becaouse it won't overload any server.

The question is: will it pay off to use signals for a list of users that contains lets say 100s or 1000s of users? I'm afraid it will slow down the whole application.

Is there any other "clear and elegant" way to do this? Django docs advices not to use signals whenever it's possible.

Comment: I'd use a job processing engine (e.g. Faktory by Contribsys). On a change put a job into the queue and let Faktory handle the rest with a dedicated process - not attached to your main application. An alternative would be to use a FAAS call in some cloud to do the processing.

Comment: This can happen using `Django-signals`, but it won't work immediately, share your repo.